# Install "Microsoft Report Viewer" on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, .net, ssrs

I am attempting to install [Microsoft Report Viewer (2015)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496) on a web server.

The web server is a **Windows Server 2012 R2 (x64)** instance.  The web server will be running a .NET application that uses the Report Viewer in an ".aspx" page.  The web server is a fresh install, with **.NET 4.6** installed, and select components from IIS and other features installed.  There is a separate web server that hosts the SQL database and SSRS.

The *System Requirements* for Report Viewer indicate .NET 3.5 or 4.0 is required, as well as **Microsoft System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server 2014** be installed.

I attempted to install SQL Server System CLR Types setup from a link provided in the *Related Resources* section, but get this error:

> Microsoft Systems CLR Types for SQL Server 2014 requires the .NET Framework version 2.0 or 3.0 or 3.5 or 4.0. Ensure that this requirement is fulfilled before installing Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2014.

MS CLR Types can be installed from the provided link, or select features can be picked from the [Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295) (click download, and check boxes of what you want).  I attempted this install method and got the same results.  I did **not** try the entire feature package.

I have looked at the registry for the server, and I see the expected versions of .NET in there.  I have looked at the *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64* directory, and see the expected folders in there.

What setup is missing or is required to get Report Viewer installed?

*(This is my first Stack Exchange universe post.  Any suggestions or edits are welcome. My site reputation has limited the amount of links/images I could include.)*

Comment: "I have looked at the registry for the server, and I see the expected versions of .NET in there. I have looked at the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64"  

What folders do you see there? .Net 4.0 and 4.6 are not the same. Try installing .Net 3.5

Comment: I tried installing .NET 4.6 and 4.0 from separate downloads, and for each I get a message like "already installed".  For 3.5, and 3.0 SP1, I get the security prompt, but the install package does not seem to run and no message is given.  In the "Framework64" folder I see "v2.0.50727", "v3.0", "v3.5", "v4.0.30319".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling .NET 3.5 resolved this problem. Could not find a source for the problem, or what was wrong with the initial installation of .NET, and wish I could provide a better answer.